# Change event.target src attr in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

On clicking image I want to change its src attribute using `event.target`.

I am trying to achieve the same using below code but it is not working; where am I going wrong?

```js
$(".sim-row-edit-img").click(function(){
 alert("Image clicked");
 $("event.target").attr("src","https://cdn.iconscout.com/icon/free/png-256/car-location-find-navigate-gps-location-29571.png");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img class="sim-row-edit-img" border="0" alt="W3Schools" src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/dtafalonso/android-l/256/WhatsApp-icon.png" width="100" height="100">
```

Answer (score 3):

`event.target` is an object , so remove the quotes from event.target

```js
$(".sim-row-edit-img").click(function() {
  alert("Image clicked");
  $(event.target).attr("src", "https://cdn.iconscout.com/icon/free/png-256/car-location-find-navigate-gps-location-29571.png");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img class="sim-row-edit-img" border="0" alt="W3Schools" src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/dtafalonso/android-l/256/WhatsApp-icon.png" width="100" height="100">
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use `$(this).attr()` as `$('event.target')` will not give you a valid `jQuery` object. Using `$(this)` will give you the reference of the clicked element and then you can change the `src` attribute of that element.

```js
$(".sim-row-edit-img").click(function() {
  alert("Image clicked");
  $(this).attr("src", "https://cdn.iconscout.com/icon/free/png-256/car-location-find-navigate-gps-location-29571.png");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img class="sim-row-edit-img" border="0" alt="W3Schools" src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/dtafalonso/android-l/256/WhatsApp-icon.png" width="100" height="100">
```

To use `event.target` you need to pass the `event` object to the function and no need to use `$(event.target)`, simply use `event.target.src = 'value'`.

```js
$(".sim-row-edit-img").click(function(event){
 alert("Image clicked");
 event.target.src = "https://cdn.iconscout.com/icon/free/png-256/car-location-find-navigate-gps-location-29571.png";
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img class="sim-row-edit-img" border="0" alt="W3Schools" src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/dtafalonso/android-l/256/WhatsApp-icon.png" width="100" height="100">
```

Comment: let me update my question, reason why i need event.target is actuaally i right click on image, context menu appears, then on the context menu i click edit and a form appears

Comment: @user2828442 you can tick mark the answer if it was helpful to you.